# Multiple class-based Google Maps Autocompletion search boxes

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am building a form in which one of the fields I need is a Google Maps location auto-completion search box. Now, these search boxes are dynamically added and they may be on different pages with different IDs.

Now, looking at the examples from previous questions, here's what I did:

HTML:

```
<input id="{{some generated ID}}" class="mapTypeField" type="text" size="50">
```

JavaScript

```
mapFields = document.getElementsByClassName('mapTypeField');

for (var i=0; i<mapFields.length; i++) {
    function initialize() {
        var input = mapFields[i];
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}
```

and it gives the following error:

> InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
>
> _.ab @ js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places:32

I am not very good with JS, what mistake might I be making? Also, is there an alternate way to do what I'm trying to?

Comment: The google autocomplete api only supports input type = text. So make sure your input type is text and not a textarea.

Comment: Yep, did that. My input type is a text. Is the above JavaScript code okay though?

Comment: is that the only error you're getting? Could you perhaps post more of your code including how the searchboxes are added? I'm a beginner but i'm sure it would help you get better answers as well.

Comment: @Bruno added the HTML and the complete error

Comment: I think your variable mapFields is a class. The class has no unique identifier but later you're using this: var input = mapFields[i]; So instead, just call your IDs instead of your class.

Comment: try using this instead: mapFields = document.getElementsByClassName('mapTypeField').id

Comment: That won't work since `mapFields` is an array. But `mapFields[i].id` would return the ID of an input element. Then I could do a `document.getElementById()` of that but that would give me the same result as `mapFields[i]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Change this:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

to:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);
```

**Here is a working JSFiddle**
https://jsfiddle.net/rdawkins/69Luo215/2/

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Comment: var input = document.getElementsByClassName('map_address');
   
        for (i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input[i]);
            google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
                place = autocomplete.getPlace();
                console.log(place);
            });    
        }    console says undefined. Please help.